# Importing all external golang modules to one file and then importing from that file?

Tags: go

Is there a way to import external modules into one file and then import from that file?

For example:

```
// externals.go
import ( 
  Bitbucket "bitbucket.org/user/project"
  Github "github.com/user/project"
)

// main.go
import (
  "externals/Bitbucket"
  "externals/Github"
)
```

Is the above in some form possible?

Comment: I don’t think so. I have not seen such a thing. But even very big projects do without these things. Maybe you can get more help by explaining the big picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. It is a specific design goal of Go
to make all dependencies explicit.

See http://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article and section 7
in particular for more detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible, not even with some tricks.